# Keycloak with Swedish BankID

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, bankid

We need to support authentication and signing with Swedish BankID together with Keycloak.

Looking for a Keycloak library for this (open source or commercial) - do you know anything about like that?

Comment: You could write and add a SPI for that. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer @JulianEgner
I was hoping that someone else have done it :)
This was a emergency-case-question  - now things were sorted out and we finalized agreement with another IAM solution than Keycloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just published a bankid identity provider for keycloak

Please try it out and give feedback.

https://github.com/bankid4keycloak/bankid4keycloak